# sql server - How to Get all distinct value in group by column from two table and count from another table for each value

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables in that 2 tables are master table and 3rd is transaction table. i need to get count from transaction table for each value in other two table without loosing rows in mater table

i need result like below

[Table layout for understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ll90p.jpg)

This is the code i have tried,

```
select s.status_name, e.machine_group_name, qty = COALESCE(COUNT(e.id),0) 
from tbl_status s
left outer JOIN tbl_transaction as e ON e.status_name = s.status_name
group by e.machine_group_name, s.status_name
```

This is solution i have figured:

```
select m.machine_group_name, s.status_name, qty = COUNT(e.id) from 
tbl_machine_group as m
cross join tbl_status as s
left outer join tbl_transaction as e on e.status_name = s.status_name
and e.machine_group_name = m.machine_group_name
group by m.machine_group_name, s.status_name
order by machine_group_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    select 
        MC_Group_Name
        ,Status_Name
        ,count(1) as [Count of Transaction]
    from 
        tbl_Transaction tbl_3
        left join tbl_Machine_Group tbl_1 
            on tbl_3.MC_Group_Name = tbl_1.MC_Group_Name
        left join tbl_Status tbl_2 
            on tbl_3.Status_Name = tbl_2.Status_Name
    group by 
        MC_Group_Name
        ,Status_Name
```